# Knockoutjs native template binding and simple array of strings

Tags: binding, mvvm, knockout.js, templatebinding, knockout-2.0

I'm trying to understand native `knockoutjs` [template binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html), especially [foreach binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html).

Just wondering how to access current item using native bidning? With `jQuery.tmpl` it is possible using something like `$item` / `$data`. How to do the same using native template binding when data source is the arrays of primitives so each item has no named fields? Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M73S8/2/) with two examples, the first - using native binding where data source is array of custom objects, second one - binding to an array of strings. I'm unable get it working, looks like I'm missing something obvious?

Basically I'm trying to understand native bindings and be able refactor following example using native binding: [JSFiddle: Comma separated list of checked items](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/EGAH9/) so I would be able keep an observable variable which represnts a comma separated list of checked items.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `$data` to access the raw value like: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/M73S8/3/.

Here is the other fiddle updated: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/EGAH9/8/.  Not sure the exact functionality that you want to support in it.

Comment: Wow, `$data` is supported as well, looks like I;ve mixed up somethign in my original script sicne tried both $data/$item as well, anyway thanks now I'm 100% sure what shall I use. Regarding second example, could you please see [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/EGAH9/), whilst checking checkboxes value of the `selectedPeople` variable reflects list of selected items, is it possible to have such template using native bidning? Thanks

Comment: Do you want `selectedPeople` to have their names or something else?

Comment: Right, this could be checkbox names or value of any other checkbox property like ID, but the main idea is to keep a list of selected items.

Comment: The `checked` binding runs off of the value of the option element, so you can store id or name or whatever you want.  If you want to store objects, then you would have to store a key (id) and then use a computed observable to represent an array of the objects.  Here is a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/EGAH9/11/

Comment: Am I right that with native binding I can not use template bidnings and `$root`? In other words is it possible doing the same but with templated `<li>`?

Comment: The native template engine can work with templates that are contained in other elements (usually script tags), so something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/EGAH9/12/ works.

Comment: You could do it without an computed observable by just using the click event and storing it into the array itself. http://jsfiddle.net/cjgaudin/Dp7Br/

Comment: @CoreyGaudin: thanks, this wokrs as well. I believe solution using  `computed` looks more interesting since it is knockoutjs-native approach

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is already answered from the amazing Niemeyer (thanks for all of your help in the Knockout Community!), but I made a jsFiddle to show storing the actual Person objects Selected in an observable array.

I am not sure if that is what you are trying to do, but maybe someone else is researching this looking on how to do this exact thing: bind the actual objects into an observable array, not just the ids (although, i added that too to remind me).

Example of a Checkbox List Selected Object Binding: http://jsfiddle.net/cjgaudin/Dp7Br/

Comment: RNiemeyer already posted a solution [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/EGAH9/11/), Anyway it is interesting see different solutions since I'm only started learning knockoutjs, thanks and +1 as a credit

Comment: Well one nice thing about this is how many different ways Knockout allows you to tackle these problems. A good framework allows complex problems to be solved a multitude of ways. This is why I love Knockout. Also, RP Niemeyer is the man when it comes to Knockout. He knows his stuff.